# How do I implement in memory or embedded kafka not for testing purposes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am looking to deploy a spring boot app in an environment that only allows Kafka to be run by the aforementioned app. My app will be a Kafka producer and consumer. Is there a way to run an in memory instance on startup that can be used for purposes other than testing? Alternatively, is there a way to startup a spring boot app that will not fail if it cannot connect to Kafka as a producer and consumer?

edit: it is a temporary solution until we are able to deploy Kafka in this environment. The app does not produce and consume its own records. It is one part of a multi app deployment where each app both produces for other apps and consumes other apps Kafka topics. I see a lot of info around app startup when Kafka is not available for a consumer, but not much is out there with regards to producers. My app will be doing both.

Comment: "each app both produces for other apps and consumes other apps Kafka topics" -- Not clear how you plan on doing this since the embedded broker does not bind to an external port

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the comment. In this specific environment there does not need to be an external connection. The app just needs to be able to interact with Kafka in some form or startup even if it fails to connect.

Comment: Sounds like you might want unit tests instead that verify the behaviour of your app before its able to be ran against an actual cluster.

Answer (score 9):

What would be the purpose of such an application (produce and consume its own records)? The embedded broker is not designed for production use.

Since version 2.3.4, the container property `missingTopicsFatal` is false by default, which will allow the container to start even if the broker is not available. With earlier versions, you can set it to false to get the same effect.

When it is true, the container connects to the broker during startup to verify that the topic(s) exist.

You can also set the container's `autoStartup=false` to prevent the container from starting at all.

**EDIT**

I wouldn't recommend using this in production, but you can remove the `test` scope from `spring-kafka-test` and declare the broker as a `@Bean`...

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
```

```java
@Bean
EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker() {
    return new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1)
            .kafkaPorts(9092)
            .brokerListProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers"); // override application property
}
```

I just tested it with this app...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63812994Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63812994Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker() {
        return new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1)
                .kafkaPorts(9092)
                .brokerListProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63812994").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63812994", topics = "so63812994")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so63812994", "foo");
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=realKafka:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

**EDIT2**

With the above configuration, other applications on the same host can connect with `localhost:9092`.

If you need remote access to this embedded broker, you will need some additional configuration:

```java
@Bean
EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker() {
    return new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1)
            .kafkaPorts(9092)
            .brokerProperty("listeners", "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,REMOTE://10.0.0.20:9093")
            .brokerProperty("advertised.listeners", "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,REMOTE://10.0.0.20:9093")
            .brokerProperty("listener.security.protocol.map", "PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,REMOTE:PLAINTEXT")
            .brokerListProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
}
```

You can then connect from other servers with `10.0.0.20:9093`.

Comment: it is a temporary solution until we are able to deploy Kafka in this environment. The app does not produce and consume its own records. It is one part of a multi app deployment where each app both produces for other apps and consumes other apps Kafka topics. I see a lot of info around app startup when Kafka is not available for a consumer, but not much is out there with regards to producers. My app will be doing both.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @hellmaca "Other apps" will be unable to connect to the embedded broker, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is simply not true; other apps on the same host can connect; to enable remote access, see the second edit to my answer.

Comment: I meant by default and not overwriting the listeners

Comment: "What would be the purpose of such an application (produce and consume its own records)?" Let's say we have a) 3 instances of an application, b) all instances share the same configuration and c) the configuration can be modified from each instance. Do you think it's a bad idea to send configuration changes to the broker only and have all changes processed via Kafka events by each instance (including the originating node)?